# Wrong accepted answers

Tags: discussion

A new phenomenon I noticed on Math.SE after I returned here after a long pause is wrong accepted (and sometimes highly upvoted) answers. Looks like when most users see such answers they assume that the question is solved, and no need to think on the question again. But when you think on the question (and on the answer) critically, you understand that the answer is plain wrong, and the questioner accepted it because he was said it is good to accept. I tried to give new answers, (which I think are correct) but they receive little or no attention, sometimes negative reaction. I want to say that I did not see wrong accepted answers before, this is new phenomenon. I think now it is more important to avoid a conflict than to be correct.

Comment: Ideally if a wrong answer gets accepted, what should happen is that future visitors should see that post and vote down that answer. Once it goes to $-1$ (say), it is clearer that the accepted answer is probably wrong or at least insufficient. If this is failing, then one of more of (1) visitors not reading posts critically, assuming blindly that the accepted answer will work and even voting it up (2) the question itself not receiving enough attention from future visitors (3) askers lacking the ability to discern what should be the "right" answer to the question , is a possible pattern.

Comment: I cannot comment on why your (which you think are correct) answers may not receive enough attention without knowing which questions you answered, so I'm not going to read into that too much, but I have also observed something similar to you recently. Without "numbers" it's difficult to measure the degree of the problem, but in my experience, it's definitely there.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I do not want to use meta to attract attention to my posts on Math.SE. This is not good anyway.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Posts with negative-score accepted answers are very rare.  Out of 1563724 questions, only 1802 have an accepted answer with net negative downvotes. Of these 1802, only 442 have a second answer with a score above 0, and of those 442, just 254 of the questions have a positive score themselves.

Comment: A common practice now is to ignore such questions and leave them as is. As far as SE is concerned everything is good: a question is answered, the answer is accepted. Nobody should rely on correctness in internet.

Comment: This happened to me yesterday. The wrong answer had four upvotes and was accepted, the correct answer had only my upvote. What can we do in such cases? It is embarrassing. In many cases, I think nothing. The wrong answer is by a regular, high reputation user, who seems to me not very inclined to discussion, so I don't want to engage in a discussion and create tensions, even if I am usually very kind in discussions. I'm sorry just for the OP and the other user, who also in comments appears as if she/he had said wrong things. I just upvoted the comments of this second answerer.